# Можно ли испустить emit из вторичного thread'a, так, чтобы слот работал в главном thread'e?

Tags: многопоточность, qt

Например в основном thread'e делаю

```
connect(this,SIGNAL(runIt(int)),obj,SLOT(run(int)));//посл. арг. ауто
_future = QtConcurrent::run(this,&Server::serverThreadAlt);//асинхронно
```

теперь serverThreadAlt вызывается в отдельном. И там уже вызываею

```
void Server::serverThreadAlt()
{

    emit runIt(0);
}
```

будет ли вызван слот run и в каком thread'e? Основном или в том же, в котором serverThreadAlt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Обработка событий производится из
> контекста принадлежности объекта к
> потоку, то есть обработка его событий
> будет производиться в том потоке,
> которому объект принадлежит.

из книги Макса Шлее "программирование на Qt 4.5"

Comment: то есть нельзя? А есть об этом в официальной документации qt?

Comment: Ну так можно сделать, но у слот будет вызван в основном потоке. Получается, что вы имитацию сигнала перенесли в другой поток, но это ничего не меняет.

Да, это есть оф. док. 
Threads and QObjects.
...
A QObject instance is said to live in the thread in which it is created. Events to that object are dispatched by that thread's event loop. The thread in which a QObject lives is available using QObject::thread().